# How long will it take to charge my solar battery full?

Tags: solar-energy

How long will it take six 100watts solar panels of 12volts each to charge four AGM batteries 200Ahm each, with 30ahm charge controller?

Comment: Depends on the sun.

Comment: What unit is Ahm? Do you mean mAH? What is the voltage of the batteries?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this depends on the sun, as well as other factors:

- Efficiency of solar panels
- Efficiency of charge controllers
- Use and performance of MTTP controller
- Other losses in the system
- What the solar panels are exposed to
- Voltage of batteries

If we assume that the 6 panels each product 100W and this can be pushed into the batteries, which we assume are 12V, the sum is simple enough: 600 W in, to charge four lots of 200Ah (assuming that's what you meant, not Ahm) at 12V, which is four lots of 2400Wh, making 9600Wh. At 600 Watts that takes: 9600/600 = 16hrs. But that ignores so many issues... Your charge controller, the capabilities of the batteries and other things.

If we change this to something more realistic:

Panels are running at 80% performance, so that's 6x100x0.8 = 480W (this is still assuming good unbroken sunlight).

Assuming these are 12V lead acid batteries, we're changing them with 15.5V, which means we have a peak of: 480/15.5 = 31 Amps. But there is the charge controller in the way. So lets assume 90% efficiency for as they can be pretty good, 480W in, 432W out. So now we're charging with 432W into 4 lots of 200AH at 12V, would be 12x200x4 = 9600Wh. So that makes about 22.3 hours.

22.3 hours unbroken perfect sunlight is all you need (based on many assumptions which you could correct once you've got the spot on value). And this still assumes perfect batteries (internal resistance will take off a lump of power depending on the current you're charging with) and no doubt other things I've ignored for now.

As mentioned in the comments this assumes that the batteries are completely dead when the charging starts. Clearly this should never be the case, and this will cause damage to batteries and shorten their useful life. But that is what the question appeared to be asking when I wrote my answer.

Comment: I think your calculation is mostly correct. This assumes the AGM batteries are completely empty when starting the charge cycle, which will hopefully almost never be the case (otherwise they would not last very long). Typical use should only discharge (and subsequently recharge) them about 50%.

Comment: I think your expectations of solar panel efficiency (80%) and presuming 100% battery charge efficiency (no heat losses) are optimistic, but your method is sound.

Comment: Thanks so much, this answered my question clearly. I am grateful.

Comment: @ComradeHilary don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick!